# Create mini-site community with Craft

Tags: plugin-development, craft-features

We are creating a new website using Craft CMS.

The main functionality of it is to let user to create their own mini-site.

All the users should have their own control panel and manage their pages and menu.
There should be url per user like `username.site-name.com/nameofthepage`
The administrator should be able to manage all mini-site

Does anyone already done something like this? Is there any plugin already done for this kind of functionality ?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Mehdi and welcome to the Craft CMS Stack Exchange! Please consider accepting Christopher's answer if it helped, or add more detail (as he suggested) to your question to increase the odds of getting a more specific answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is no plugin that provides this type of functionality but there really isn't any need for one either. Depending on how many pages their mini-sites needs to be, this really can all be handled with front-end entry forms and how complicated it can get is entirely up to you.

You should create their control-panel's using routes (possibly not even necessary depending on how you structure it). There you'd allow for any of the entry forms, etc.

In order to give more advice on how to go about this we'd really need more detail on exactly what each of these multi-sites needs to be capable of but this just seems like a standard site allowing unique front-end entry creation which is all able to be done without the use of any plugins, even while allowing it to get quite advanced and complicated.